# Apply a Meta tag to one page only

Tags: plugins, html

I'm working on a [IP Locator](http://nix-pix.co.uk/ip) Service, and I want to display a Customized Google Map which shows the visitor's location. It works fine [here](http://n1x.co.uk/geo.html), but I don't know how to incorporate it into my Blog.

I've got the "html/javascript in  Wordpress" Plugin, but I also need to apply a few Meta tags to the page. Is there any plugin/tweak that allows to add a meta tag *only* to one page?

Please Help!!

**Edit: I also need to include javascript (< script>< /script>). How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Both involve using a [conditional tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). I don't know which conditional you'll need to test for, hence the "{something}" placeholder. (If I had to guess, you may use the `is_page( $ID )` tag.)

### Edit your theme header file.

It's usually called `header.php`:

```
if( is_{something}() ) {
    echo '<meta ......... />';
}
```

### Use the `wp_head` hook in your `functions.php` file

```
function wpse_54694() {
    if( is_{something}() ) {
        echo '<meta ......... />';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_54694' );
```